# How do I unpublish a .Net application

Tags: c#, .net

I published a C# .net application to the wrong folder. I am using VS 2005. How do I unpublish the app to be able to republish in the correct folder.

I tried simply publishing to another folder and now the app will not run from either location.

Comment: Publishing to a certain folder shouldn't matter to the application. What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to manually delete all the published files from the wrong folder.

There is no "recall"/"unpublish" function in VS. All "publish" does is compile and copy compiled files and other included files and folders (images, css, js etc) to the specified directory.

Answer (score 3):

Publishing is essentially just a copy of the built application to the destination folder, as far as I aware. This points to a different problem in your application as being the source of your error.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely your app isn't working from either folder because it's configured to use asp.net 1.1 or doesn't have asp.net installed at all on the server.  If it is installed, and both 1.1 and 2.0+ are installed, it will default to 1.1, and the folder needs to be configured to use 2.0+.

But other than that, you just delete the files from the server by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing function also creates "Application" on the IIS, so I would probably start by opening the IIS server with "Internet information services manager", and remove the application with the wrong folder.

Comment: in another words, if you remove the files from the folder, there will be still a site in the IIS with a name of your application pointing to the old wrong location.